# issue with typeorm modules (Module '"typeorm"' has no exported member 'DataSourceOptions')

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm

I'm getting an error, when launching the project, using docker-compose-up

[image: error]

I have packages in package.json:

"@nestjs/typeorm": "^8.0.2",
"typeorm": "^0.2.22"

I tried to set up "typeorm": "^0.2.45" and got the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataSource` and `DataSourceOptions` are added in version **`^0.3.0`**. [more](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#030-2022-03-17).

You need to update the typeorm's version to **0.3.x**, or you can use `Connection` and `ConnectionOptions` instead.

> Connection, ConnectionOptions are deprecated, new names to use are: DataSource and DataSourceOptions